# Substrate front end template "yarn install" error

Tags: substrate

I am following the basic tutorial of Substrate "Create your first Substrate blockchain"
and I am getting an error while trying to install dependencies of
"substrate-front-end-template".

[Screenshot of error given on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSQq9.png)

Comment: P.s I use Macbook Pro M1 late 2020 macos Monterey 12.1 and all my packages of yarn, node, rust are updated to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Got the error solved. It was due to node version, as soon as i downgraded it to v16 it worked like a charm and the frontend template installed the dependencies using "yarn install" and the server ran with no issues.

Comment: I was super stuck on this! Downgrading to v16 worked for me too.